# Upload large files using aws sdk multipart upload

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

While I am trying to upload a large file using the high level API code provided on the AWS site using the AWS SDK I am unable to do so and the application stops with unexpected error although I have provided the right parameters.

This is my code:

```
static string existingBucketName = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
static string keyName            = "filename";
static string filePath           = "D:\file.txt";

try
{
    TransferUtility fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1));

    TransferUtilityUploadRequest fileTransferUtilityRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
    {
        BucketName = existingBucketName,
        FilePath = filePath,
        StorageClass = S3StorageClass.ReducedRedundancy,
        PartSize = 6291456, // 6 MB.
        Key = keyName,
        CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
    };

    fileTransferUtilityRequest.Metadata.Add("param1", "Value1");
    fileTransferUtilityRequest.Metadata.Add("param2", "Value2");
    fileTransferUtility.Upload(fileTransferUtilityRequest);
    Console.WriteLine("Upload 4 completed");
}
catch (AmazonS3Exception s3Exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s3Exception.Message, s3Exception.InnerException);
}
```

The same file when uploaded with low level API gets uploaded without error but takes lot of time . So I was hoping that the high level API might get it uploaded faster. Or is there any other method for uploading large files using the SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just needed to upgrade my app from **.Net version 4.0** to **.Net version 4.5** and it works.